# For positive number $a,b$, when $a,b$ satisfies $2a^2 +7ab+3b^2=7$, what is maximum value of $a+{\sqrt{3ab}}+2b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, substitution

Question is

> For positive numbers $a,b$ such that $2a^2 +7ab+3b^2 = 7$, what is the maximum value of $a+{\sqrt{3ab}}+2b$?

I use AM-GM Inequality to do this

$$(2a+b)(a+3b)=7\text{ and }2a+b=\frac{7}{a+3b}.$$

So, maximum value $m$ is $\frac{7}{a+3b}+{\sqrt{3ab}}$ so $m=\frac{7}{2{\sqrt{3ab}}}+{\sqrt{3ab}}$ is $2{\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}}$ so $2m^2=28$.

But it didn't satisfy equal condition so how do I get it?

Comment: There are several inaccuracies in the post which make it hard to understand. Please check your work before showing it to others! 
What do you mean by "satisfied $2a^2+7ab+3b^2$"? This is an expression, not a condition. I thought maybe you want this expression be zero, but that is impossible, since $a,b>0$. So what is the condition exactly?

Comment: Your approach doesn’t make much sense, even if your answer turns up correct. If $2a+b=\dfrac7{a+3b}$, how do you substitute that for $a+2b$?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is right!

Indeed, we'll prove that $\sqrt{14}$ is a maximal value.

Let $a=x^2$ and $b=3y^2$, where $x$ and $y$ are positives.

Thus, $2a^2+7ab+3b^2=2x^4+21x^2y^2+27y^4$ and we need to prove that
$$x^2+3xy+6y^2\leq\sqrt{14}$$ or
$$(x^2+3xy+6y^2)^2\leq2(2x^4+21x^2y^2+27y^4)$$ or
$$(x-y)^2(x^2+6y^2)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

The equality occurs for $b=3a$, which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: Is not the maximal value should be $\sqrt{14}+(b'-a')$? Since what we pay attention to is 
$$ a + 2b + \sqrt{3ab} = b + 2a + \sqrt{3ab} + (b-a) \le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3ab}} + \sqrt{3ab} + (b-a) $$

Comment: @Arief Anbiya I showed that $a+\sqrt{3ab}+b\leq\sqrt{14}$ and showed that the equality occurs. Thus, $\sqrt{14}$ is a maximal value.

Comment: Ok, right. But where do you get the idea of $\sqrt{14}$ in the 1st place?

Comment: @Arief Anbiya I just saw the topic-starter's attempts.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is when you apply AM-GM in the last step. Applying it you get $\ge$ inequality, which corresponds to the minimal value of l.h.s, not maximal.

---

Also $m \le \frac{7}{2\sqrt{3ab}} + \sqrt{3ab}$, not equal.

**UPD:** You did the following 
$m = \frac{7}{a + 3b} + \sqrt{3ab} \le \frac{7}{2\sqrt{3ab}} + \sqrt{3ab} \ge 2\sqrt{\frac 72}$ and that's it. You get $2\sqrt{\frac 72}$ as maximal value.

Comment: Thanks I know ablout that but I'm right the answer is 28

Comment: That's my question why I'm right??

Comment: @user366725 I've updated my answer. Please see if this version clears things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a＝x^2,b＝3y^2$ and $t＝\frac{x}{y}$,only need to find the maxium of this
$$\frac{7(t^2+3t+6)^2}{2t^4+21t^2+2}$$
and ...
[image]